# reactJs recharts connectNulls with dotted line

Tags: java, reactjs, svg, recharts

I have a line chart with multiple lines on it depending on API response,

I may get `null` if there is no data exist and in result my graph line get break.

instead of breaking the line I wanted to join that data points using dashed line simmiler to this high chart [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mtg6bd0o/3/)

`connectNulls` is also available in recharts but draws line similar to others, I want to draw dotted line to differentiate it with other ones.

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out a strategy for this? I would also find this very helpful.

Comment: @geoff didn't found anything

Comment: I actually came up with a slightly hacky solution that works well. I wrote an algorithm to identify all the null "paths" that should be connected (so for example, the x,y coordinates corresponding to those two gray dots) and drew line segments with `<ReferenceLine strokeDasharray=... />` for each of those paths. It actually ends up looking really nice.

Comment: @geoff can you put the algorithm?

Comment: @geoff then they should add it as a prop in Line API if your algo works, try creating a pr

Comment: At the very least I'll write up a minimal example of how I did it, if it seems like this is a common issue.